# Android Studio Run configuration error

Tags: android, android-studio, run-configuration

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question I have no one else to turn to for help ...  My android studio was working fine a couple of days back and run configuration was also ok but now i am having issue with it ... I am getting a cross ( x ) sign over the android icon please have a look at the images below

A cross on the little android icon

[image]

---

Also when I try to edit the run configuration I see a error at the bottom please have a look at this image

Error visible in the edit run configuration dialogue

[image]

Comment: Did you try clicking the "fix" button ? If yes, what is happening ?

Comment: @vakman .. yes I did ... it takes me to the signing option but I am not generating a signed APK ... just trying to debug the app

Comment: i like the way you have started your question and admitted what you have done

Comment: @gvsharma .. Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the build variant from the bottom left panel to `debug` and you should be able to run it fine from Android studio.  It will use the default debug signing configuration in this case.

You cannot run a `release` build variant directly unless you specify the signing config explicitly under `bulidTypes - > release`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to build a release apk. If you do this you need to sign it. If that's the case check out this:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

If not you need to switch your configuration to debug.

Comment: Gone through the documentation and it really helped ... thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: You guys are the best ... stackoverflow rocks